# Import complex types from another XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am finding difficulty in importing and referencing a complex type from one XSD file to another. Let me illustrate my scenario with an example

**Student.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="xyz"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:common="xyz"
    xmlns="xyz"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="student" type="student" />

    <xsd:complexType name="student">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="birth-date" type="xsd:date" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here is another XSD, Teacher.xsd, where I would like to reference the complex type student from student.xsd

**Teacher.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="xyz"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:common="xyz"
    xmlns="xyz"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import schemaLocation="student.xsd"
        namespace="xyzzz" />

    <xsd:element name="teacher" type="teacher" />

    <xsd:complexType name="teacher">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />

            // TODO - Refer to student from student.xsd

        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I have seen other Stack Overflow posts regarding the syntax for achieving this like

```
<xs:element name="teacher" type="teacher:teacher"/>
```

along with import:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="xyz" namespace="xyz"/>
```

but nothing seems to be working.

Can someone help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `xsd:include` rather than `xsd:import` since the XSDs are in the same namespace.

**Notes**

- You'll want to include Student.xsd, not common.xsd.
- Since the type being referenced is in the same namespace, you don't need to specify a namespace prefix:

  ```
  <xsd:element name="student" type="student"/>
  ```
- It's better style to name your elements and attributes differently.

**See also**

- [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085)
- [How to reference element in other XSD's namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700999/how-to-reference-element-in-other-xsds-namespace)  (for complete, working example of `xsd:import` use for when namespaces differ)

Comment: I need to reference complex types from other namespace as well. Can you help me with the code for that ?

Comment: I've added a link to a complete, working example of how to use `xsd:import`.

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to reference complex type student in teacher "Invalid attribute value for 'ref' in element 'element'. Recorded reason: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'student:student' as a QName: the prefix 'student' is not declared" . Can you please check?

Comment: Hi, I have asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685305/import-complex-types-from-xsd-in-different-namespace . Can you please look into it ? Thanks a lot