# Import complex types from XSD in different namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have two XSD files in different namespaces like below

**book_request.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="book-request"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="book-request"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="book-request" type="book-request"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="book-request">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="booking-code" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="room-type-code" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="customer-ip-address" type="xsd:string" 
                         minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="booking-amount" type="xsd:double"/>
            <xsd:element name="customer" type="customer"/>
            <xsd:element name="payment" type="payment"/>
            <xsd:element name="provisional-book-id" type="xsd:string"
                         minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="customer">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="first-name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="middle-name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

---

**provisional_book_request.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="provisional-book-request"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:common="common"
    xmlns="provisional-book-request"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import schemaLocation="book_request.xsd" namespace="book-request"/>

    <xsd:element name="provisional-book-request" type="provisional-book-request"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="provisional-book-request">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="nri" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element name="hotel-id" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="check-in-date" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element name="check-out-date" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element name="customer" type="customer:customer"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I am trying to import the complex type `customer` from book_request.xsd to provisional_book_request.xsd and I try to achieve it by `<xsd:element name="customer" type="customer:customer"/>`

But I face the following error

> "Invalid attribute value for 'ref' in element 'element'. Recorded
>   reason: UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'customer:customer' as a
>   QName: the prefix 'customer' is not declared."

As I am very new to XSD, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a namespace prefix for the imported namespace in **provisional_book_request.xsd**,

```
<xsd:schema

     xmlns:br="book-request"

>
```

and use it to reference the imported type:

```
<xsd:element name="customer" type="br:customer"/>
```

then your error will go away.

---

Here is the full **provisional_book_request.xsd**, corrected as described:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="provisional-book-request"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="provisional-book-request"
    xmlns:br="book-request"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="book_request.xsd" namespace="book-request"/>
  <xsd:element name="provisional-book-request" type="provisional-book-request"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="provisional-book-request">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="nri" type="xsd:boolean"/>
      <xsd:element name="hotel-id" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="check-in-date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="check-out-date" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="customer" type="br:customer"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```