# XSD targetNamespace does not override element namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD that defines an complex type and has the `targetNamespace` attribute set.  Is it correct that the `TestElement` will not gain the namespace set by `targetNamespace`?   It should gain the namespace from the complex type `afn:ElementType` and therefore `http://anotherfancy.namespace`, right?

```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:sfn="http://somefancy.namespace"
            xmlns:afn="http://anotherfancy.namespace"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="http://somefancy.namespace"
            version="1.0">
      <xs:import namespace="http://anotherfancy.namespace" schemaLocation="..."/>
      <xs:element name="MyComplexType">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TestElement" type="afn:ElementType">
               </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When `xs:schema/elementFormDefault="qualified"`

<sup>(As in your case, which is also the recommended and most commonly used setting of `elementFormDefault`.)</sup>

The ***elements*** declared within an XSD must be in the namespace given by the XSD's `targetNamespace`.

Therefore, for your XSD, `TestElement` will have to be in the `http://somefancy.namespace` for the XML document to be valid.  If you instead want it to be in the `http://anotherfancy.namespace`, declare the ***element*** in the imported XSD; storing its ***type*** there will not place the element itself in that other namespace.  Once `TestElement` is declared in the imported namespace, it can be used in the original namespace via `xs:element/@ref`.

See also [How to reference element in other XSD's namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36700999/290085)

### For rarely needed, and generally not recommended, other variations

See [Michael Kay's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398647/290085) and [my longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085) to this question: [What does elementFormDefault do in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463138/290085)

Comment: This isn't the full story; it ignores the difference between local and global element declarations, and the impact of `form` and `elementFormDefault`.

Comment: @MichaelKay: True, I should have elaborated, or at least mentioned, `elementFormDefault`  et al considerations.  Answer updated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace of an element declared in a local element declaration is given in the following rule (XSD 1.1 part 1 §3.3.2.3)

```
{target namespace}

The appropriate case among the following:
1 If targetNamespace is present [as an attribute of the xs:element element], then its ·actual value·.
2 If targetNamespace is not present and one of the following is true
2.1 form = qualified
2.2 form is absent and the <schema> ancestor has elementFormDefault = qualified
then the ·actual value· of the targetNamespace [attribute] of the ancestor <schema> element information item, or ·absent· if there is none.
3 otherwise ·absent·.
```

The `targetNamespace` attribute of `xs:element` is new in 1.1, so for 1.0 you can ignore rule 1.

The `form` attribute of `xs:element` is very rarely used, but if the value is `qualified` then the element goes in the targetNamespace declared on the containing `xs:schema`, while if it is `unqualified` then it goes in no namespace. If `form` is not specified (which is nearly always the case), then it defaults to the value of `elementFormDefault` on the `xs:schema` element. This is usually set to `qualified`, so the element goes in the target namespace of the schema; but the default (unfortunately) is `unqualified` which means it goes in no namespace.