# Configure an XSD to consist of multiple xs:schemas?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD file in which I would like to place several diagrams, with a description of the services. When adding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="[target1]"
            xmlns:tns="[target1]">

</xsd:schema>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="[target2]"
            xmlns:tns="[target2]">
</xsd:schema>
```

I get error: "**Multiple root tags**"

If I write like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="[target1]"
            xmlns:tns="[target1]">
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="[target2]"
            xmlns:tns="[target2]">
    </xsd:schema>
</xsd:schema>
```

I get error:

> Invalid content was found starting with element  '{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":schema}'. One of
> '{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":simpleType,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":complexType,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":group,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attributeGroup,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":element,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attribute,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":notation,
> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":annotation}' is expected.

**Is it possible to configure an XSD file to consist of multiple schemas `xsd:schema`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSDs cannot be composed by embedding `xsd:schema` elements like that.

To incorporate multiple XSDs with distinct `targetNamespace`s, use [`xsd:import`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#composition-schemaImport).

### See also

- [How to reference element in other XSD's namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36700999/290085)
- [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085)

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to have one schema, but this schema can declare several elements suitable as root, and underneath those you could have completely disjunct tree structures.

Comment: so I can just change the second schema's <xsd:schema to <xsd:element and everything will work?

Comment: I wanted to add a second schema so that different queries have their own targetNamespace. It doesn't work with the element.

Comment: One schema - one target namespace I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there any way to add a link to each request?